# Error while installing Laravel 8 using Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-8

I am new to Laravel. I installed Composer globally on the "C:" drive and installed XAMP too. But after that, when I try to install Laravel, it gives me the error on CL, and hence the setup breaks.

> [InvalidArgumentException] Composer could not find the config file:
> C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin To initialize a project, please create a
> composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/
> "Getting Started" section

I searched a lot for this but couldn't find any relevant thing to it.

Comment: can you write to the selected directory without escalating to administrator (```C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin```)? What composer command is used to install/create new laravel project?

Comment: composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app   
this is the command i use to create project in C:/xampp/htdocs/projectname

Comment: Please add some clarification to your question by editing - where do you run that command?

Comment: my issue is that while installing laravel, it breakdown the setup and give the above mentioned error 
InvalidArgumentException] Composer could not find the config file: C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

Comment: i am running in this command in htdocs folder

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it. Do you have any clue why it complains about that specific directory?

Comment: no I don't have clue

Comment: What does `composer diagnose` yield?

Comment: is their need to set up any environment variable for installing it

Answer (score -1):

install composer with this link: https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe

and open setup and use recommended settings

then unchecked the developer mode and next on prompt then select this path in your c drive if your xampp install in c drive.

```
    C:\xampp\php\php.exe
```

Then next may be you have the checkbox underneath so do check it, then in proxy page left it blank and then next and install then wait and next and finish.

Then go to cmd and type in root user:

```
    composer
```

If you see this scree then composer is installed succesfully :

```
 / ____/___  ____ ___  ____  ____  ________  _____
 / /   / __ \/ __ `__ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ _ \/ ___/
/ /___/ /_/ / / / / / / /_/ / /_/ (__  )  __/ /
\____/\____/_/ /_/ /_/ .___/\____/____/\___/_/
                    /_/
Composer version 2.1.3 2021-06-09 16:31:20
```

Now go to htdocs in xampp then go to search bar and type cmd in it and cmd open in the selected folder of xampp.

Then type:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel YOUR NAME
```

If you see this line:

```
Application key set successfully.
```

Then Your project is created.

Enjoy Developing!!!

Comment: the composer is installed already with the above mentioned steps, the issue i am facing is that while i am trying to install laravel using commands 
s

Comment: Please share more details. What makes you think that Composer was not installed in the first place? How should it throw an error if it wasn't installed?

Comment: @NicoHaase as i mentioned in my question that the composer was already installed, i installed it using zip file setup file and for checking I am using CL and write "composer"